# How to enter Text or click outside a JFrame using Java

Tags: java

My Goal:
I am trying to make a program which will log me into my zoom classes at the correct time. I have figured out everything except trying to open zoom, enter the ID and passcode correctly, and logging in to the class.

---

The Problem:
There is no API which I can use to achieve my goal. There is a certain Zoom API, but it is paid, and I am a minor. The only option I think is left is to make java click and enter text anywhere outside a JFrame.
I tried using java.awt.Robot for this, but it can only click on a button inside the JFrame. I tried overlapping the two buttons and keeping the zoom window focused, but Java changes the focus to the JFrame.

---

If there is any other alternative in Java, or if there is any other external Library or API that may come in use, please suggest me the same.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Set an alarm on your computer and when the alarm goes off, log into Zoom manually.

Comment: thats the problem. I am bored of logging in to my school website, opening the pdf, copying the ID, blah blah. I started this projects to get rid of the hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried using java.awt.Robot for this, but it can only click on a button inside the JFrame.

The Robot can be used to generate an OS level event.

If you want the Robot to click out side the frame then you need to move the mouse outside the bounds of the frame.

Simple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setLocation(25, 25);
    frame.setSize(100, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.delay(2000);
    robot.mouseMove(15, 15 );
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}
```

The Robot will click the system menu of the window found at the top/left corner of your desktop. So make sure you have a window maximized.

Answer (score 1):

You could use WindowListener,#windowDeactivated or WindowFocusListener#windowLostFocus, but you have to be careful with owned JDialog's (as you have to be with FocusListener anyway)

Comment: I did not understand clearly. Can you please explain?? Also I wanted to add text in a Text Box of a window. Is it possible to do it with WindowListener?